# Public transportation to Sir El Danniyeh

Tags: public-transport, buses, lebanon

Is there any public transportation from Beirut or Tripoli to [Sir El Danniyeh](https://www.google.com/maps/@34.3899422,36.0256194,14z)?

And if yes, how can a Westerner with no knowledge of Lebanese find the (presumably) bus?

Comment: It seems real hard. There's no information on https://www.facebook.com/LebaneseCommutingCompanylcc/ the website link leads to a parked domain. The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCFTC page leads to a dead end too. I can't find a link from the [tourism page](http://www.mot.gov.lb/) to either OCFTC or LCC.

Comment: You are aware that everything beyond Beirut is quite dangerous to visit?

Comment: @chx hard to find online doesn't necessarily imply hard to do. In many countries bus schedules are simply part of local knowledge.

Comment: @JonathanReez Not everything beyond Beirut if I can trust the various travel advises. E.g. the UK has a nice map of parts to avoid: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/57b313f4ed915d0870000000/160811_Lebanon_pdf.pdf

Comment: @pnuts Something like leaves when full and forget it when dark is good as a schedule for me. In most countries that is indeed what happens.

Comment: @ptityeti Ask people if all else Fails. Younger people in Beirut are very likely to know at least some English, while older people often speak French

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct bus no you dont have , you can go from beirut [Cola Station](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cola+Station+-+Gas+Station/@33.874627,35.495882,16z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x349f1309de2404f4!8m2!3d33.8751434!4d35.4954073) to [Tripoli](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tripoli,+Lebanon/@34.4235953,35.8113116,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x1521f6ab9db89d33:0x323c52527dde8578!8m2!3d34.4346642!4d35.8360291) then you can get a cab from there (but note if you want to get a cab they will charge you alot if they know you as a tourist generally for a citizen around 3$-4$ for a tourrist 15$-20$). 
As for safety I advised to be careful as lebanon is at threat especially after [they caught suicide bomber before exploding himself](http://www.dailystar.com.lb/News/Lebanon-News/2017/Jan-23/390537-sidonians-aghast-at-hamra-bombing-attempt.ashx).
*Anyway if anyone need help in lebanon I can help :)*